# wsl2 frozen (unable to run any distro). Can I recover data? Windows 11

Tags: linux, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

Long story sort - WSL2 hangs forever until the system reboots while trying to perform any operation on any distribution. I've tried to play with starting/stopping LxssManager, but nothing seems to work. **At this point I just want to recover data from the distribution.** Is it possible without access to shell through WSL?

Some more details.

- I can perform most WSL commands like `wsl -l -v` at system start before trying to open or perform any action related to the distribution
- After trying to run the distribution, WSL freezes forever until system reboot. Commands previously running are now hanging indefinitely, so for example I can't perform `wsl -l -v` after attempting to start the distribution. `wsl --help` works fine, and the same with `wsl --set-default-version`.
- `wsl --export` hangs, so I can't use it.
- commands like `wsl`, `wsl --status`, `wsl --shutdown` hangs WSL.
- I've installed another distribution and despite it being installed, trying to run it causes the same issue.

Some WSL info (my system language is Polish so names may vary)

```
wsl --version

Susbsystem WSL version: 1.1.6.0
Kernel version: 5.15.90.1
Service WSLg version: 1.0.50
MSRDC version: 1.2.3770
Direct3D version: 1.608.2-61064218
DXCore version: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Windows system version: 10.0.22621.1485
```

Comment: For the future, you might consider putting all your important data in a Windows folder instead of a Linux one.  You can use soft links to make it seamless.

Comment: I've tried such attempt some time ago, however the "proxy" or whatever such link is called seems to have huge impact on read/write performance. It wasn't pleasant to use WSL like that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Yes*, data recovery is possible. WSL 2 stores distribution data in `.vhd` disk images. Unfortunately, where they are located varies wildly. I found [this script on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/bashonubuntuonwindows/comments/t5d6l0/get_list_of_all_wsl_distributions_their_locations/) (going by the username, from fellow Super User contributor NotTheDr01ds?):

```
Get-ChildItem HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss\ |
    ForEach-Object {
        (Get-ItemProperty $_.PSPATH) | Select-Object DistributionName,BasePath
    } | Format-List
```

It works on my machine. Just paste it in a PowerShell window, and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Inside the folder this script reports, you’ll find an *ext4.vhd* file. Simply copy this file wherever and you have a backup. You can access this backup using compatible virtual machine software ([Hyper-V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-V), [VirtualBox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox), and others after converting the image format) with Linux inside the VM. The disk image does not contain any partition scheme, only an *ext4* filesystem. You could mount it like this (read-only so as not to make unintended changes):

```
mount -o ro /dev/sdx /mnt/wsl-rescue
```

You can then find the data from your distribution at `/mnt/wsl-rescue` and copy them somewhere else.

You can use any modern Linux for this rescue. For example, an Ubuntu live DVD image would do, and installation is not required.

After backing up your data, you can then proceed with restoring WSL—if need be by fully resetting it.

Comment: Lol - Beat me by a few seconds, it seems ;-)

Comment: I do recommend using `Format-List` in this case, since (at least on my system) the path is truncated for longer Package names.

Comment: Also, you include the good advice to recover the data from another Linux, which mine lacks.

Comment: Thanks! I've been searching for hours to finally get the answer how wsl stores data for distros! In my case location of ext4.vhdx is `/AppData/Local/Packages/CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu_{some_unique_key}/LocalState`. Now I can access my data :) Thanks!